# Wordpress website consuming huge bandwidth on 404 pages

Tags: wordpress, bandwidth, http-status-code-404

I am running a website on Wordpress and there is a lot of bandwidth consumption because of hits on 404.

[image showing the url being targeted to generate 404..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcfMw.png)

I am sure that the url "/wp-includes/Text/Diff/1.php" is being accessed from outside the WP and no file within my website is redirecting to this which also makes me sure that someone is trying to may be hack my website or slow it down by exceeding my bandwidth limit.

I need some help in order to sort out this problem...

Comment: Have you considered putting Cloudflare in front of your website? They filter out a lot of bad traffic. If it still hits your server you could do a number of things to mitigate this - use a firewall to drop the requests, or send a smaller 404. Are you on shared hosting, VPS, etc, and what web server?

Comment: Hello Dear, I'm doing a job as a web developer and services like cloudflare are out of my budget. Yesterday, I created a blank php file with the same name as "/wp-includes/Text/Diff/1.php" so it will only return a blank page without adding numbers to the bandwidth. The bandwidth consumption decreased a lot with it but still this page is getting hit. I just want to stop the hits on that page.
You suggested me to add a firewall, please let me know whether to install it on CPanel or Wordpress..
Thank you so much..

Answer (score 0):

You basically want to find out...

How do I skip Wordpress's 404 handling?

Been answered before:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/24587/how-do-i-skip-wordpresss-404-handling-and-redirect-all-404-errors-for-static-fi

Let your webserver handle it so you don't ever hit the resource intensive PHP/MySQL combo.

Comment: Hello Jay,
I think I want to block every ip address which hits the page "wp-includes/Text/Diff/1.php"..
Or may be block every ip address which is hitting the website in a loop if it is possible..

Comment: Fail2Ban is perfect solution for condition based banning.

Comment: Great, I'll let you know if I face any issue in the configuration. Thank you so much.